# Where do I find the stylesheets for Mozilla firefox developer tools themes

Tags: firefox, themes

The mozilla firefox developer tools has two different themes, a light and a dark. The dark is the default theme for Firefox developer, the light is the default theme for the normal Firefox.

I would like to find the actual stylesheets (assuming that these are styled with stylesheets) to edit them. I am on Windows currently and I assume that since I cannot find them in appData that they must be inside some .exe or.dll that I can access using resource hacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles used for DevTools window in Mozilla are in `omni.ja` zipped file.
In current Firefox version, there are two omni.ja files:
this ZIP file contains resource files for DevTools: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\omni.ja"
this ZIP file contains other resource files. Not used by DevTools: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\omni.ja"

Resource hacker, to change DLL or EXE files is not needed.
omni.ja are standard (deflate) ZIP files, without added signature or other trickery.
To change styles, you are mostly interested in css files inside the omni.ja.

Let me show you on an example how to customize one of in-build themes.
For this example, I will change color to highlight a headings in Inspector/Rules section of DevTools.
I wanted it highlighted, because I use to look-up CSS rules in DevTools Inspector and I am mostly interested in rules for "This Element".
I was getting annoyed that I often oversaw, that I already scrolled past the "This Element" into the "Inherited ..." sections.
In Dark Theme, it looks like this:

[image]

In following example I'll show how I changed its style to this result to highlight the section header:

[image]

## How to find the responsible style selector

You can go through css files in omni.ja one by one and use try & error method to make a test modification on a bunch of rules in the css, then see the result.

But that's not the best option as there is a great tool in Firefox for just this purpose.
[Browser Toolbox - how to activate and use it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox#Enabling_the_Browser_Toolbox)

You can then use DevTools on DevTools to Inspect the Inspector:

[image]

Now we have quickly figured out that the selector we need for this example is `.ruleview-header` and that it's defined in the `rules.css` file.
We can also click on the `rules.css` to see it's contents directly in FF.
This is the overriding rule, which will change the header's color as it is in the second picture above:

```
.ruleview-header {
    background: #905252 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

or to follow the same scheme as is used in css files in omni.ja, this is what I modified/added in existing css file (One I added has "added" keyword in a comment, ones I modified have "was:" keyword showing original value)

```
/* CSS Variables specific to this panel that aren't defined by the themes */
:root {
    --rule-header-color: var(--theme-toolbar-color); /* to keep light theme as it was */
}

:root.theme-dark {
    /* was: --rule-header-background-color: #222225; */
    --rule-header-background-color: #905252 !important;
    --rule-header-color: white; /* added */
}

/* Rule View Container */

.ruleview-header {
    /* was: color: var(--theme-toolbar-color); */
    color: var(--rule-header-color) !important;
}


/* expandable headers will follow the style of .ruleview-header,
   but here it can by styled separately */

.ruleview-expandable-header {
    /* background-color: YOUR_COLOR !important; */
}

.ruleview-expandable-header:hover {
    /* was: background-color: var(--theme-toolbar-background-hover); */
}
```

## Where to put the modifications

- You can edit the actual rules.css file and pack it back to omni.ja file, but after FF update, your changes will be lost.
- Edit `userChrome.css` file and add it [where it should be.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0yJTa4sjdAhVETrwKHV9qD4cQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkb.mozillazine.org%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUserChrome.css%26printable%3Dyes&usg=AOvVaw05R0Eb5WdAM5__PkPfNvBl). In this case, you must use !important on all overwriting rules.
- Use an Extension, such as Stylus
- create your own Extension

I think in most cases, using `userChrome.css` file is the best option.

## View resource files direcly in Firefox

some folders/files can be viewed using chrome: and resource: pseudo protocols.

files in skin folder, e.g.:
path in zip: .\chrome\devtools\skin\dark-theme.css
chrome://devtools/skin/dark-theme.css
* Can't list directory. Must enter full path including filename

files in themes folder, e.g.:
path in zip: .\chrome\devtools\modules\devtools\client\themes\variables.css
resource://devtools/client/themes/variables.css
* Can also list directory: resource://devtools/client/themes/

## For more reading:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793285/3273963
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147992/customize-firefox-developer-dev-tools-color-theme
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442661/firefox-quantum-developer-tools-theme
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/personalize-firefox-dev-tools-theme/
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6qalvm/how_to_change_the_developer_tools_dark_theme_back/